# cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken error when trying to use a different key to decrypt a cypher with FERNET

Tags: python, python-cryptography, fernet

So I was basically trying to create a script that would continuously generate keys and hypothetically brute force finding the correct key for the decryption, and running it outputs [this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XF6EX.png)

This is the script:

```py
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

x = "test"

key = Fernet.generate_key()
f = Fernet(key)

x_encrypted = f.encrypt(x.encode())

while True:

    key = Fernet.generate_key()
    f = Fernet(key)

    print(f.decrypt(x_encrypted))  # decoding variable x until it outputs "test" (hypothetical)
```

*Any information about what's causing this would be greatly appreciated!*

Comment: Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask]